# How to realize like spring @ConditionalOnMissingBean in Quarkus

Tags: spring, quarkus

for example in spring, i can create Bean use @ConditionalOnMissingBean when it not existence

```java
  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean(AuthCache.class)
  public AuthCache authCache() {
    return new DefaultRedisCache();
  }
```

Comment: Not everyone is familiar with both spring and quarkus. You could describe what you try to achieve and I'm sure someone will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is Quarkus's `@DefaultBean`.

See the [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#default_beans) for more information.